# MySQL database design problem

Tags: mysql, database

I have design problem, which I would love to get a hand with. I normally don't have problems with designing databases, but this one gives me some trouble. :)
I'm making a program which is basically a task-manager, where you can create Activities and Events. An Activity may or may not have an Event associated with it, and an Event will have one to many associations.
How do I design the Event database? Since every Event can have more than one association, will I need to make a table for each Event? Where the tablename is it's unique name? I'm completely blank.
Thanks

Comment: Explain better: you have Activities objects that can have zero, one or more Events objects. Events are related only with activities or with something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since every Event can have more than one association, will I need to make a table for each Event?

No. You need some version of:

```
Activity
--------
ActivityID
ActivityDescription

Event
-----
EventID
EventDescription

EventActivity
-------------
EventID
ActivityID
```

Then, to list an Event with all its Activities:

```
SELECT * from Event
LEFT OUTER JOIN EventActivity ON Event.EventID = EventActivity.EventID
LEFT OUTER JOIN JOIN Activity ON Activity.ActivityID = EventActivity.ActivityID
```

You need the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of the usual `INNER JOIN` in case there are no Activities for the event.

Comment: @egrunin: using your answer (+1 for you) I give OP a query to catch all items... I hope you agree :)

Comment: Looks like what I need. :)
To clarify something: I need an input in EventActivity for each Activity in there? So if I had an Event with ID 1, and two activities which were associated with that event, with ID 1 and 2, I would have two lines in that database saying: "1, 1" and "1, 2"? :)

Comment: Yes, you add one row to EventActivity when you want to connect an Activity with an Event.

Answer (score 1):

Well starting with the obvious:

```
Event(evid PK, event details)
Activity(actid PK, activity details)
EventActivityRelationship(evid FK, actid FK)  -- both make the primary key together

-- where PK is primary key and FK is foreign key
```

Then to make a link between an event and an activity, all you need to do is to add the two ID's together to the relationship table.

And keep in mind, relational databases (basically anything that's not NoSQL) grow downward (they gain rows), never horizontally (never in columns or tables) as you add more data. That will help you make intuitive database designs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the easy-to-understand answer. :)
As I'm far from an expert in this, it has become really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using @egrunin answer, if you need to get all activities and events you can use:

```
SELECT a.ActivityID, e.EventID
FROM Activity a
LEFT JOIN EventActivity ea
ON a.ActivityID = ea.ActivityID
LEFT JOIN Event e
ON ea.EventID = e.EventID
```